# React Component renders in Dev Tools but not in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**UPDATE** - Found an error in on one of my redux reducers

I have a component that shows a list of other components, but the Child Components never show up in the DOM. However they appear in the React Dev Tools.

**Parent:**

```
 ...
        <div className="description">
          <div className="ui header">Pick the page you would like to link up with your community</div>
          <p>We have grabbed these pages from your Facebook account. Just pick one an click done to sync up!</p>
        </div>
        <div className="ui segments">
          {props.pages.map((p, i) => <Page pickPage={props.pickPage} page={p} key={i} />)}
        </div>
 ...
```

**Child:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Page = props => (
  <div className="ui segment page" onClick={() => props.pickPage(props.page.toJS())}>
    <div className="ui grid">
      <div className="ui fifteen wide column">
        <h4>
        {props.page.get('name')}
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div className="ui one wide column">
        {props.page.get('picked') ? <i className="ui big right floated green check icon"/> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Page;
```

As you can maybe see I'm using Immutable.js for my props and Redux (if that has any relevance)

I really have no idea why this is happening, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And you don't get any error messages in the console, right?

Comment: @markthethomas no.. This is my React Dev Tools: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uk8v1abxjgcm94/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2016.28.45.png?dl=0  And this is my DOM: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0p5egb4tilr1om/Screenshot%202015-12-16%2016.29.40.png?dl=0

Comment: Weird. And the DOM shows nothing? Can you include a screenshot of that, too? What does RDT show for the context, props, etc. for your `<Page>` components?

Comment: maybe making the return in the page component render explicit?

Comment: Nevemind. It was a kind of stupid error in one of my reducers, that somehow didn't show op in the console. 
I was returning a state that didn't match with the one I expected...
Thank you for the help though!